# Android, send push notification to myself

Tags: android, push-notification

I want to an user send a push notification for himself.

Is there a way to do that without using Google Cloud Messaging?

It is offline, just show a notification on his own phone.

Thanks.

Comment: To just show a notification on the *same* phone? At a specific time or what?

Comment: yes, exactly, simple as that. A service that sends notification, like an alarm.

Comment: do you want something like a local push notifications?
if thats the case you can use NotificationManager and NotificationCompat.Builder

Comment: Yes, I want to do it locally

Comment: check out the docs about building and sending a notification
http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

example for building and sending a notification:

from: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html

```
// prepare intent which is triggered if the
// notification is selected

Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

// build notification
// the addAction re-use the same intent to keep the example short
Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
    .setContentText("Subject")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "Call", pIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "More", pIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "And more", pIntent).build();


NotificationManager notificationManager = 
  (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0, n);
```

you can edit the notification as you like.

also helpful:

http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html

happy coding...